# Cannot start YAP anymore on Windows 10 - "MiKTeX encountered an internal error."

Tags: yap

Since six weeks or two months YAP does not work for me anymore.

May be, Windows 10's update 1607 was performed then. But I'm not sure.

Message in "MiKTeX Problem Report" is "MiKTeX encountered an internal error.", Data-field is empty. Complete report below.
This error occurs in both cases: when started from command line WITH and WITHOUT a -DVI-filename. It occurs as well, if started from "Start".
MiKTeX-update was frequently done.

Any idea? I would appreciate it very much! I have to run `dvipdfm` now, to check my changes. That's VERY timeconsuming due to the 10,000 graphics included.

Many thanks in advance!

Regard
Radler

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\mfmodes.cpp
Line: 50
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 14393
Invokers: cmd
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Franz\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Franz\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Franz\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Franz\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Franz\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Comment: try ask this question on  miktex-users-request@lists.sourceforge.net.

Comment: Same problem here. Updatef my about one year old miktex installation unsing the update manager. Now I have exactly the same problem. Except for the windows user name path the error report is absolutely similiar.

Comment: yap takes a long time running and stop working after a few minutes, without obtaining any results.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it's quite simple. Run Miktex settings (Admin). Under General/Maintenance you have to refresh FNDB and update formats.

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

This Yap "solution" Did not work for me either. I think think the whole latex distribution is in a mess. I would not mind paying some money in exchange for a reliable solution.  It is high time something was done about it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/230792)

Comment: Kindly review the first comment to this question. This place is not intended to be a discussion forum, which can be puzzling in the beginning. Thanks